# ORACLE Retrieving data from 4 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate-functions

I have the following tables:

`Students(id, name, surname)`

`Courses(course id)`

`Course_Signup(id, student_id, course_id, year)`

`Grades(signup_id, mark)`

I want to display all the students(id, name, surname) with their final grade (where final grade = avg of the grades of all courses), but only for the students that have passed all the courses for which they have sign-up in the current year.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT s."id", s."name", s."surname", AVG(g."mark") AS "finalGrade"
FROM "STUDENT" s,
    "course sign-up" csn
join "GRADES" g
on csn."id" = g."signup_id"
WHERE csn."year" >= '01-01-2022'
HAVING "finalGrade" >= 5.00
GROUP BY s."id"
```

However, after adding the last 2 lines, regarding the `finalGrade` condition, I get an invalid identifier error. Why is that?

Comment: First, GROUP BY comes before HAVING. Then, the select clause is executed after the HAVING clause, so the alias finalGrade is not known there. And have you really made your database case sensitive, so you must use quotes for every column name? Then, don't mix explicit joins with comma joins. Don't use comma joins at all. Then, your year column holds strings that consist of day, month and year? Why?

Comment: Exactly, @Thorsten. Except one thing: GROUP BY and HAVING clause can be used in that order or vice versa, it doesn't matter - query will still work. How do I know? Just tried it! But yes, I always use them that way (GROUP BY followed by HAVING).

Comment: They have passed all courses when the average grade is at least five? Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, oh. Did you really create tables using lower letter case names enclosed into double quotes? If so, get rid of them (the sooner, the better) because they only cause problems.

Apart from that, uniformly use joins - in your `from` clause there's the `student` table which isn't joined to any other table and results in cross join.

Don't compare dates to strings; use date literal (as I did), or `to_date` function with appropriate format model.

As of error you got: you can't reference expression's alias ("finalGrade") *as is* in the `having` clause - use the whole expression.

Also, `group by` should contain all non-aggregated columns from the `select` column list.

This "fixes" error you got, but - I suggest you consider *everything* I said:

```
SELECT s."id", s."name", s."surname", AVG(g."mark") AS "finalGrade"
FROM "STUDENT" s,
    "course sign-up" csn
join "GRADES" g
on csn."id" = g."signup_id"
WHERE csn."year" >= date '2022-01-01'
GROUP BY s."id", s."name", s."surname"
HAVING AVG(g."mark") >= 5.00
```